# Power shell Script to Open a Web Page and Bypass SSL Certificate Errors and check if website is up or down

Tags: windows, powershell, monitoring

We have few URL's which are internal individual server URL like  "https://Servername:port/name/-Username-Logon#abc" and we need these URL's to be monitored 24/7 .
I ran into an issue with my powershell script because the page I was trying to access was secured with SSL and we were using a self-signed certificate. This causes Internet Explorer to redirect to a warning page rather than going straight to the site. I found a way to bypass this warning page as below but unable to monitor these URL's after bypassing the page.

Can you please let me know if there is a way to monitor ?

"Starting Internet Explorer in Background"

```
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible=$true
$uri = 'https://Servername:port/name/-Username-Logon#abc'
$ie.navigate("$uri")
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100};
if ($ie.document.url -Match "invalidcert")`enter code here`
{
 "Bypassing SSL Certificate Error Page";
  $sslbypass=$ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a") | where-object {$_.id -eq "overridelink"};`
  $sslbypass.click();
  start-sleep -s 10;``
     };
```

Comment: Have you considered installing the self-signed certificate as trusted (or perhaps using a certificate you can validate against a trusted root)?

Comment: I advise against using an internet explorer COM object for this: use Invoke-webrequest. In Powershell 7 you have a skipcertificatecheck parameter (or whatever the parameter is called), in PS3, 4 and 5 you can use a small callback method for this